# angular route weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular.js app. I have a defined route like this

```
/client/:clientid/app/:appid/v/:appversionid/contentmgmt/nav/:entityid/:instanceid/:addInstanceTo?
```

addInstanceTo is optional.

I want to change the hash to

```
#/client/d9d2acc3-3d00-444d-a293-96c2b4e1e73c/app/a4bd2525-1820-49df-b2eb-606586b40870/v/all/contentmgmt/nav/regions/8559696e-b786-47a1-986f-e50318d89654
```

However angular also appends the default param to my route like so

```
 #/client/d9d2acc3-3d00-444d-a293-96c2b4e1e73c/app/a4bd2525-1820-49df-b2eb-606586b40870/v/all/contentmgmt/nav/regions/8559696e-b786-47a1-986f-e50318d89654/:addInstanceTo
```

Any ideas why this behaviour?

Comment: Why is there a `?` after :addInstanceTo ?

Comment: Isn't that how you define options route parameters?

Comment: I guess you're using ui-router. I though there was something to place after `?`, else, this is useless. And :addInstance is already optional. You can retrieve it through `$stateParams` object